# WPF4 DatePicker - adding time

Tags: wpf, datetime, wpf-controls, datetimepicker

Now that there is an official MS DatePicker in WPF4, I was wondering if there was a way to let it edit the Time part of a DateTime as well.  I can't see anything, but it seems rather obvious to have missed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any 'Time' functionality built into the DatePicker out of the box in .NET 4

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx

You might be able to create a custom control that uses the DatePicker for the Date portion, or possibly even create a ControlTemplate for the DatePicker to add a Time Selection element... but no... it's not built in for us unfortunately.